# Using time stamps as input to Neural Networks to reconstruct particle tracks

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing, real-time

So here's the thing: consider a detector, made of several vertical strings, each hosting 60 sensors distributed equidistantly, as shown in the following picture (dark dots are sensors):
[image: IceCube detector grid]

Particles will then flow through and produce pulses on each sensor that you can use. Informations include time of passing by, coordinates (stringnumber+position on string or cartesian coordinates), total charge, etc.

The final goal is to reconstruct angles of incoming particles and their energies. Though we first just consider a simple classification problem of finding out whether the particle came in form the north or south hemisphere (i.e. from the top or bottom direction of the detector.

As input values we use every timestamp of each sensor, their exact position hasn't to be passed as it will be encoded by the position of the timestamp in the input list.
The problem we have is with sensor that didn't detect any particle. Is it clever to insert their timestamp as `float("Inf")`? Leaving their time as zero is another option, but it will then be ambiguous with the sensor that triggered as first (having timestamps normalised to [0,1]).

I'd be glad to hear any hint from people who have already worked with timestamps in neural networks. Also, if you have any good idea on developing NN's for our future tasks please share them! The planned approach are convolutional (deep) neural networks, but we still have to think about how to encode sensor-positions in that irregular hexagonal shape.

Answer (score 3):

For the reason you mentioned, it is unwise to set the time to 0. It is also unwise to set the time to infinity, because the neural network will not be able to cope with such an input.

Instead, for each timestamp input, you should also incorporate corresponding a one-hot boolean vector to indicate whether a particle passed through the sensor or not. If not, then it is ok to leave the timestamp as 0.

Feed both the timestamps and the indicator vectors into the network.